# Am I being overly critical of these window installations?

Tags: drywall, windows, remodeling, cutting, window-frame

We are replacing all of the windows in our house, which is a few dozen. We are doing new construction style. The crew is only about 20% done, but already I've noticed a few issues that concern me. I'd like to know if I'm overreacting or not. The company has a good reputation, and if this is seriously bad work, I'd like to bring it up to the management now before even more work is done. But I don't want to overstep my bounds either. Below are 5 images in order of decreasing concern:

1. This window is clearly not level, even to the naked eye, it is rotated a bit counterclockwise. I have not brought this up with the crew yet as they just finished it before leaving. But I suspect they are finished, as there are already 12 screws securing the entire perimeter, and they've also started installing the flashing over the fins.

[image]

2. Same as above, measuring with an actual level. The windowsill is level.

[image]

3. Every window opening in the house needs to be cut back a bit (depth-wise, from the outside) to fit the new windows that have deeper frames than the old ones. Some of the cuts they are making into the sills and drywall and pretty shoddy IMO. It concerns me more in the sill (below), since they are destroying good solid wood. The gap in this image ranges from 0" (at the left) to 0.25" (at the right).

[image]

4. Same as above, but this time in the drywall. Again the max gap is 0.25", but it is very inconsistent, the cut line is not even close to straight.

[image]

5. Another not-straight drywall cut line, maxing out the gap at 0.25". I have pointed these out to the crew and they've just shrugged and said caulking will fix it. I believe 0.25" is about the max you want to stretch caulk, and I don't think that is a good excuse for cutting such raggedy lines. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I stopped reading at `But I don't want to overstep my bounds` ... you are the paying customer ... talk to the supervisor

Comment: You can talk to the supervisor, but don’t show him your “level”. Btw, drywall cuts get fixed with more drywall, so nobody expects them to be beautiful cuts. Wood, well, that might be another matter, depending on how it’s being finished. If it is caulk, 1/4” is pushing it.

Comment: window install is rough framing even on new construction.  1/4" isn't terrible.  trim and caulking will hide that kind of thing.  new construction you leave 2" extra (1" on left / 1" on right) on the dimensions to achieve level and plumb and have room for shims/spacers.

Comment: Are they finished, and not planning on coming back to caulk?